# How can I resample dates in Python without losing non-integer variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, integer, resampling

I have large data frames within a dictionary, and am running a loop on the datetimeindex of each dataframe to resample per day. Resampling the mean per day is working fine, but the new data frames within the dictionary have lost all columns that contain objects instead of integers. **How can I keep columns that contain non-numeric data while still resampling all numeric data?**  This is an example of the beginning dataframe and it's subsequent columns.

```
d_bac_s[1].head()

                                  project_id  ... rainfall_previoustwodays
Date/time (EASTERN STANDARD TIME)             ...                         
1989-06-01 11:15:00                   CSORWM  ...                      0.0
1989-06-01 11:15:00                   CSORWM  ...                      0.0

d_bac_s[1].columns

Index(['project_id', 'subregion', 'dep_segment', 'station_id',
       'surface_bottom', 'depth', 'enterococcus_count',
       'Enterococcus '<' or  '>'', 'ecoli_count', 'E. coli    '<' or  '>'',
       'fecalcoliform_count', 'Fecal coliform '<' or  '>'', 'rainfall_current',
       'rainfall_previousoneday', 'rainfall_previoustwodays'],
      dtype='object')
```

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
dbacsurfacedate = {}
for key, df in d_bac_s.items():
    df = df.resample('D').mean()
    dbacsurfacedate[key] = df
```

Here is the same data frame and columns after the resample.

```
 dbacsurfacedate[1].head()

                                   station_id  ...  rainfall_previoustwodays
Date/time (EASTERN STANDARD TIME)              ...                          
1989-06-01                                1.0  ...                       0.0
1989-06-02                                NaN  ...                       NaN

dbacsurfacedate[1].columns

Index(['station_id', 'depth', 'enterococcus_count', 'ecoli_count',
       'fecalcoliform_count', 'rainfall_current', 'rainfall_previousoneday',
       'rainfall_previoustwodays'],
      dtype='object')
```

As noted, the only columns that are missing are those with non-integer values. Example: `project_id`, or `surface_bottom`. I'm beginner python user, forgive me if this is not correctly worded.